# Database for opening times of locations

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm designing a database for opening times and created this solution.

[image]

The specifications of the database which will be a MySQL are, that a location have standard opening times in a week and can have special opening times for example on christmas or something like that.

So if I want the opening times of an entry I would first search in 'special_opening' for the given day and if it given no results back, I would load the data from 'opening'.

Is this a legit way to realize the database? 
Are there better ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify your design and make it more powerful by keeping all of the opening times in a single table which includes a date range and a priority code for resolving conflicting records.

It would look something like this:

```
create table OPENING
( id INT
, entry_id INT
, from_date DATE
, to_date DATE
, priority INT
, weekday_id INT
, start TIME
, end TIME
, pause_start TIME
, pause_end TIME
, editor_id INT
, timestamp TIMESTAMP
)
```

The differences to note between your model and this one are:

- You keep one set of records for each date range that applies instead of just having the current data.
- You can keep a date range history of opening hours.  This also allows you to future date ranges which is handy for getting data set up in advance.
- You keep regular hours and exceptions in a single table, so you don't need to have conditional logic in retrieving the opening hours.
- Exceptions have a date range also, often a range of one day if that is what applies.
- All records have a priority level.  Regular records have a low priority, exceptional records have a higher priority.  When reading just select top 1 order by priority descending.

Comment: What's the use of the weekday_id when there's the from_date and to_date?

Comment: @notflip Business hours typically follow a pattern which depends on the day of the week. The date range is meant to cover a long range not day by day.  For example for the whole summer the business is open until 10:00pm on Thursdays. That's why day of the week is tracked separately and not derived from a specific date. It would be tedious to maintain a record for each date.

Comment: @JoelBrown, A couple of questions. When you have a time range of one day, should the week_id also be set? On the other hand, if there is an established schedule and you want to mark that one day of that schedule is closed, how is the exception added? Is a new tuple inserted with the date and no value in start column? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mr.Mars If you have a time range of one day, the weekday_id is derivable with a date conversion routine.  However, for simplicity of your code I would recommend that you always set the weekday_id, even when you could derive it programmatically.  For an exception where you want to indicate being closed when another (less specific) rule says open, you need to have a convention that your code recognizes.  This could be something like start time and end time are both 00:00:00.  To indicate that the closed status is an override, add a record for the exception with a higher priority.